# Function runs before prior finishes

Tags: javascript, function

I'm currently having issues with having a function run before the one before it runs. I've tried callbacks, checking to see if has run with variables and a few other methods but none of them seem to work.

How I've basically got it set up:

```
function example() {
    f1('param');

    forloop

    f2('param');
}
```

f2 is running before f1 finishes which is strange because f1 is just `document.getElementById(elemId).innerHTML = '';`.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/spedwards/R4F8L/

**Can someone tell me why f2 is running before f1?**

(f1 is `clearPage` on line 41 and f2 is `writeToPage` on line 35)

Comment: What makes you say that `f2` runs before `f1` finishes?

Comment: Holy crap, the `ai` function is a mess. There is a ton of duplicated code in there, and 9 levels of control flow nesting are far too many to be readable or maintainable.

Comment: @user2357112 Not asking about the ai function. The duplicated code is there for every scenario, just haven't got around to cleaning it up. Either way I figured out what my problem was.

Comment: Is it only IE problem? IE8-9 has such bugs.

Comment: @Pinal No it was something I forgot to add into my code. See my answer (and I actually prefer IE9+ over Firefox)

Comment: You should have included the fact that user has to press and release Shift-key to replicate the effect.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that my problem was that the array that the page was writing from wasn't clearing itself for a fresh restart which made it appear like nothing happened.